I'm getting an error when calling AddGPS when using Shiny.Net Maui
I'm getting the following error
'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddGps' and no accessible extension method 'AddGps'
When I'm trying to call AddGPS
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseShiny()
        .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
        .UseSkiaSharp(true)


        .UseMauiPdfView()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            fonts.AddFont("font-awesome-5-free-solid.otf", "FontAwesomeSolid");
            fonts.AddFont("font-awesome-5-free-regular.otf", "FontAwesomeRegular");
        });

    builder.Services.AddGps();
    builder.Services.AddGps<NucleusGPSDelegate>();

    return builder.Build();

}
I have looked at the Shiny samples, which work fine, so it looks like I'm missing something. Does anyone have a clue what I need to add/change/do?

AddGPS is an extension method in the Shiny namespace

OK. I'm including the following using:
using Shiny;
I can't see any difference, apart from code I need for my existing project, that differs from the code in the Shiny.Net sample project.

do you have all the relevant packages installed?  Does VS provide any suggested fixes for the error?

Yes, I have all the relevant packages installed. There are no useful suggested fixes.

The Maui project includes a Windows sub-project. Shiny.net does not support Windows. Once the Windows sub-project was removed, the error disappeared and the project compiled.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
